# Is it safe to send a password via a Socket created by the default SSLSocketFactory?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, password-encryption, sslsocketfactory

Without second thought, I sent a password over a connection made using a `Socket` created by the default `SSLSocketFactory` in Java. For `SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()`, the documentation states the following:

> Returns the default SSL socket factory.
>   The first time this method is called, the security property `ssl.SocketFactory.provider` is examined. If it is non-null, a class by that name is loaded and instantiated. If that is successful and the object is an instance of `SSLSocketFactory`, it is made the default SSL socket factory.
>
> Otherwise, this method returns `SSLContext.getDefault().getSocketFactory()`. If that call fails, an inoperative factory is returned.

I'm sure that Java isn't trying to trick me, but since this was my first time doing this I wanted to make sure that it was something I can rely on for password encryption.

EDIT: At the end of the property data for "Set-Cookie" in the server response it says "HttpOnly" and then "Secure". I'm assuming that this means that the server has acknowledged that the connection was secure, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: *"I'm assuming that this means that __the server has acknowledged that the connection was secure__, but I am not 100% sure."* - Wrong. The `secure` attribute to a cookie says nothing about the current connection but means that the client should send the cookie only back with HTTPS. And even HTTPS does not actually mean security since it might be that the client for example does not properly check the servers certificate.

Comment: Safe from what? What potential attack are you asking about? Are you asking whether `SSLSocketFactory` ever returns a socket that doesn't use TLS? (No, it won't.) What is more important is who you are sending the password to, and that means that you need to make sure your trust anchors are set up correctly.

Comment: The connection is secure as long as you haven't enabled an anonymous cipher suite and provided the server certificate is checked appropriately.

Comment: @user207421 I have only done what I mentioned in my post. With that said, *I don't think I checked the server certificate*. This isn't to say that I don't trust the server that I am sending the credentials to.

Comment: @erickson I just wanted to make sure that my data can't be seen by an eavesdropper: https://serverfault.com/questions/19360/who-can-eavesdrop-on-a-users-http-traffic

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for the info, I forgot that certificates need to be checked when a connection is established since I was making a web-scraper specific to one website that I trust. Nonetheless I will be sure to take this into account if I ever have to make a more dynamic HTTP-based program.

Comment: *"...I was making a web-scraper specific to one website that I trust..."* - Validating a certificate and trusting the server are different things. Validation of the certificate is to make sure that you talk to the **expected** server instead of some man in the middle. Successful validation does not mean that you can trust the server. Similar trusting a server does not mean that you can skip validation of the certificate.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich It looks like I have a fatal misunderstanding of this. Thank you giving me your time and patience with this, it is helping me understand this better. I will go and do some research/studying online on how this exactly works as well as how to validate certificates.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a socket via the default `SSLSocketFactory`, and don't configure anything else with the relevant system and security properties, a set of certificate authorities bundled with your Java runtime is used. Glossing over [some details,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#CustomizingStores) this is a trust store found in your JRE installation at `lib/security/cacerts`. The certificates included there those of widely accepted certificate authorities, similar to the list your browser might use.

So, if the server you connect to uses a certificate issued though one of these well-known authorities, the certificate will be validated, or the connection will fail.

This ensures that a trusted authority certified the identity of the party to whom you are connected. As long as their private key hasn't been stolen, you can rely on the name bound in the certificate.

But, you need to verify the host name to ensure that the certificate presented by the server matches the host name that you expect. This happens automatically when you use the `URL` class, but you need to set the `HostNameVerifier` explicitly when using `SSLSocket` directly.

Finally, even after you know who you are talking to, you still have to exercise judgment in the information you disclose to them. That's not a technical problem though.